# Java Long - Bit's manipulation

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I have a long number and I want to manipulate it bits in following way:

```
Long l = "11000000011" (long l 's bit representation)

Long ll1 = "110000000" (remove last two bits from l and convert to Long)

Long ll2 = "11" (keep last two bit's of l and discard other bits and convert to Long)
```

Can anybody help me, how to do this in Java in a fast way ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Please update the question to more accurately reflect what you're asking; right now you're asking the opposite of what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert a string of bits into a long, you can use [`Long.parseLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
long l = Long.parseLong("11000000011", 2);
```

You can then use the bit-shifting operators `>>`, `<<`, and `>>>` to drop off the lower bits.  For example:

```
long ll1 = l >>> 2;
```

To drop off all but the top two bits, you can use [`Long.bitCount`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#bitCount%28long%29) to count the bits, then shift off the remaining bits.

```
long ll2 = l >>> (Long.bitCount(ll1) - 2);
```

**EDIT:** Since the question you're asking has to do with going from `long`s to the bits of the longs, you should use the [`Long.toBinaryString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toBinaryString%28long%29) method for this:

```
String bits = Long.toBinaryString(/* value */);
```

From there, to drop off the last two bits you can use simple string manipulation.  Try using `String.substring` for this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I should mention I have Longs not as String of bits. And from that Long, I want to get bits. I just use those as an example.

Comment: And from that long I want to get last two bits (from L to R).

Comment: Ah, okay.  That's a completely different question.  You can use the `Long.toBinaryString` function to get a binary string from a long, and from there can then do standard string manipulations to manipulate the bits.  You can see the documentation for all of the Long methods here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toBinaryString(long)

Comment: Thanks. I found another way also.

Answer (score 0):

```
 long l = Long.parseLong("11110", 2) ;
 long ll1 = l >>> 2;
 long lb = (l & 1) ; last bit
 long ls = l >>> 1;
 long lb1 = (ls & 1) ; bit before last bit
```